# Does this Euler #19 actually work?

Tags: java

I'm doing Project Euler #19 and I'm wondering how my code works.

> #### Project Euler #19
>
> You are given the following information, but you may prefer to do some
>   research for yourself.
>
> - 1 Jan 1900 was a Monday.
> - Thirty days has September,
>     April, June and
>     November.
>     All the rest have thirty-one,
>     Saving February alone,
>     Which has twenty-eight, rain or shine.
>     And on leap years, twenty-nine.
> - A leap year occurs on any year evenly divisible by 4, but not on a
>     century unless it is divisible by 400.
>
> How many Sundays fell on the first of the month during the twentieth century (1 Jan 1901 to 31 Dec
>   2000)?

#### My code:

```
static int weekday = 1;
static int sundays = 0;
static int years = 1901;
static int[] monthArray = {31, 29, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31};

public static void solve() {

    for (int yr = years; yr <= 2000; yr++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 12; j++) {

            if (j != 1) {
                months(monthArray[j]);
            } else {
                if(yr % 4 == 0 && yr % 400 != 0) {
                    months(monthArray[1]);
                } else {
                    months(monthArray[2]);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println(sundays);

}

public static void months(int monthLength) {
    for (int i = 0; i <= monthLength; i++) {

        if (weekday == 7 && i == 1) {
            sundays++;
        }

        if (weekday == 7) {
            weekday = 0;
        }

        weekday++;
    }
}
```

I thought I would have to put "j++" into the leap year so the code would jump over the next month in the array. Another thing is that I wondered why I can't start the 'months' method's for loop and weekday from 1. Is this even a bit of code that counts sundays reliably from other timespans? I get the right answer for the requested timespan, but I'm not sure if it actually works. Thanks.

EDIT: I changed the code so that the for loop with 'j' iterates through the months pretty linearly with the exception that is not in the array. Still not 100% sure if it's correct, but it seems a lot more logically sound.

```
public static void solve() {

    for (int yr = years; yr <= 2000; yr++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < 12; j++) {

            if (yr % 4 == 0 && yr % 400 != 0 && j == 1) {
                months(29);
            } else {
                months(monthArray[j]);
            }
        }
    }

    System.out.println(sundays);

}

public static void months(int monthLength) {
    for (int i = 0; i < monthLength; i++) {

        if (weekday == 7 && i == 1) {
            sundays++;
        }

        if (weekday == 7) {
            weekday = 1;
        } else {
            weekday++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you copy the subject of the Euler's challenge ?

Comment: @Cyrbil, it's "Counting Sundays" and the problem is to count "How many Sundays fell on the first of the month during the twentieth century (1 Jan 1901 to 31 Dec 2000)?"

Comment: leap years are `(year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0) || year % 400 == 0` and whenever it fires use the february array index `months(monthArray[j]+1)` and remove the 29 to keep the rest of the year intact

Comment: I don't think this will work. When j>=2 (month >= March), the number of days in the month will be wrong. Try a solution without both versions of February in the array, and treat February as the special case.

Comment: Can you write down an invariant for the for-loop that uses `j`? In other words: what is the exact meaning of the variable `j` in that loop? If you write that down you will notice that for `j >= 2` the code is not correct. Perhaps by chance you get the correct result, but then your algorithm will fail for other timespans.

Answer (score 0):

I don't wanna give too much because this site involve personal research and being stuck is a part of the game (give a try to another challenge, come back ... you will see things more clearly)

One way to do it is like that:

```
counter is 0
day_counter start on a monday
for every years between 1900 and 2000:
    for each months in that year:
        add month's number of day modulo 7 to day_counter
        if 7 divide day_counter:
            increment counter

at the end, counter is your solution.
```

Answer (score 0):

My code in JS:

```
var sunday=0;
for (var year = 1901; year <= 2000; year++) {
    for (var month = 1; month <= 12; month++) {
        if ((new Date(year, month, 1)).getDay() == 0) {
            sunday++;
        }
    }
}

window.alert(sunday);
```